# CCRotateTo animation not working properly in iOS 9.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, ios9.2

I have a problem in CCRotateto animation in iOS 9.2.1.

My CCRotateTo is working in iOS 8 but when I update iOS to iOS 9.2.1 it is having bug in animation.

The rotation not working perfectly.

Here is the code

```
[animation runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.25f], [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.25f angle:45], [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.25 angle:0], [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:4.5f], nil]]];
```

Comment: What his the problem exactly ?

Comment: @OlivierPIERRE My animation not working as per provide rotation ,it is just shows flickering animation.